# How to Define Extension Method for ICollection<T> where T : IMyInterface without Specifying T in the Method Definition

Tags: c#, generics, automapper, extension-methods

Background: I want to hook in business rules at the point that DTOs are being mapped to entities. I figured encapsulating the mapping into an extension method would be a good route.

IEntityDto is the interface that all DTOs that can be directly mapped to entities implement.

The single instance works fine:

```
public static TEntity MapTo<TEntity>(this IEntityDto dto)
{
    ... Run Business Rules that don't require db access ...
    return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TEntity>(dto);
}
```

I'd like to also extend ICollection the same way:

```
public static ICollection<TEntity> MapToCollection<TEntity>(this ICollection<IEntityDto> dtos)
{
    ... Run Business Rules that don't require db access ...
    return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ICollection<TEntity>>(dtos);
}
```

Unfortunately, MapToCollection does not show up on the context menu or compile when applied to an ICollection of IEntityDto.

What am I missing to get this to work? Do I need to just extend ICollection where T is IEntityDto? I'd prefer to not have to include the DTO type when calling the extension method.

```
public static ICollection<TEntity>MapToCollection<TDto,TEntity>(this ICollection<TDto> dtos) where TDto: IEntityDto
{
    ... Do Work and Return ...
}
```

The above works, but I was hoping to infer T from the collection.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're using an `ICollection<IEntityDto>` rather than an `ICollection<T>` for some `T` that implements `IEntityDto`? They're not the same thing at all.

Comment: @Luizgrs: TEntity does not implement IEntityDto. I'm just wrapping the mapping that Automapper is doing from DTO to Entity.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's exactly what I'm doing incorrectly. Is there a way to define the extension method for ICollection<T> where T is IEntityDto without explicitly adding T to the method definition?

Comment: No, there isn't - but there are ways of doing it in two hops. I suggest you change your question, which currently claims it doesn't work when you're using an `ICollection<IEntityDto>` (which would actually work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *effectively* need a method with a signature of

```
public static ICollection<TEntity> MapToCollection<TEntity, TEntityDto>(
    this ICollection<TEntityDto> dtos)
    where TEntityDto : IEntityDto
```

... but that would force you to specify *both* type arguments, which I understand you don't want to do.

What you can do instead is go in two hops, e.g.

```
public static class DtoExtensions
{
    public static CollectionMapper<TEntityDto> Map(this ICollection<TEntityDto> dtos)
        where TEntityDto : IEntityDto
    {
        return new CollectionMapper<TEntityDto>(dtos);
    }
}

public class CollectionMapper<TEntityDto> where TEntityDto : IEntityDto
{
    private readonly ICollection<TEntityDto> dtos;

    public CollectionMapper(ICollection<TEntityDto> dtos)
    {
        this.dtos = dtos;
    }

    public ICollection<TEntity> To<TEntity>()
    {
        // Business rules...
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ICollection<TEntity>>(dtos);
    }
}
```

You can now use:

```
var result = collection.Map().To<FooEntity>();
```

The `Map` call infers `TEntityDto`, and you specify `TEntity` in the `To` call.

Comment: `To()` -> `To<TEntity>()`

Comment: @PetSerAl: Whoops, yes. Done :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this happens because the variable that you want to call this extension method on is not actually of type `ICollection<IEntityDto>` but of type `ICollection<MyEntityDto>` for example.

Try this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static ICollection<TEntity> MapToCollection<TEntity, TEntityDto>(
        this ICollection<TEntityDto> dtos) where TEntityDto : IEntityDto
    {
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ICollection<TEntity>>(dtos);
    }        
}
```

This method accepts a generic `ICollection<TEntityDto>` instead of `ICollection<IEntityDto>` which makes it work for cases like `ICollection<MyEntityDto>`.

Here is how you would use it:

```
Collection<MyEntityDto> collection = ...

var result = collection.MapToCollection<MyEntity, MyEntityDto>();
```