# Implicit defined generic types, is this possible?

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

I currently want to write a generic extension method. If every generic type is availible in the parameters, I do not need to define the generic types:

```
//Extension Method
public static GridBoundColumnBuilder<TModel>
     BoundEnum<TModel, TValue>(this GridColumnFactory<TModel> factory,
         Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression);

//I can call It this way, whitout setting <TModel, TValue>
columns.BoundEnum(c => c.SomeProp);
```

If I want to add a generic type, that is not covered in the parameters, I need to set `<TModel, TValue>`:

```
//Extension Method
public static GridBoundColumnBuilder<TModel>
    BoundEnum<TModel, TValue, TEnum>(this GridColumnFactory<TModel> factory,
         Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)

//How it works:
columns.BoundEnum<TModel, TValue, TEnum>(c => c.SomeProp);
```

Is there a way that I can only write this?

```
columns.BoundEnum<TEnum>(c => c.SomeProp);
```

---

**Edit**: This is the full Method:

```
public static GridBoundColumnBuilder<TModel>
     BoundEnum<TModel, TValue, TEnum>(this GridColumnFactory<TModel> factory,
              Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    where TModel : class
    where TEnum : struct, IComparable
{
    return factory.ForeignKey(expression, EnumHelper.ToSelectList<TEnum>());
}
```

Comment: Short version: no. The C# reference (did you read it) seems clear enough to me; you must provide all types, if inference is not possible. That said, it's not really clear what you're asking. In your code example, the `TEnum` type does not appear to actually be used. So what's the point of it? What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: You can have [double hop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34930742): `columns.BoundExpression(c => c.SomeProp).BoundEnum<TEnum>()`.

Comment: I basicly want to get the type of an enumeration in my extension method. I didn't shown the complete method. @PetSerAl `EnumHelper.ToSelectList` gives me a select list with the description attributes of the enum

Comment: Thank you @PetSerAl, I like this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler cannot infer all generic types then you have to pass them all. There's no support for partial inference.